# Let's clean up some meta tags!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, moderation, editing

It came to my attention that some tags are currently "abused" as meta tags.

A meta tag is a tag that tells nothing about the *question*. In particular easy candidates are the publishing avenues of claims:

- if a question is about *email* then [email](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) is appropriate
- if a question is about something read in an *email* then [email](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) is used as a meta tag.

Please help by cleaning the following tags:

- "claim" a tag by putting your name next to it
- go through all the questions and remove it *only when not appropriate*
- "mark" the tag as done by putting "done" next to it.

*Do not add a missing tag here, propose it as an answer!*

---

For all these tags, "leave it" for questions about "it", "remove it" for questions found in "it":

- <del>[email](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)</del> done
- <del>[internet](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)</del> done
- <del>[news](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/news)</del> done
- <del>[media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media)</del> done
- <del>[social-media](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)</del> done
- <del>[books](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books)</del> done
- <del>[movies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies)</del> done

---

Other tags abused as meta-tags:

- [politics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) - Not all said by a politician is about politics
- [drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugs) - This should be burninated into either [recreational-drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-drugs) or [medications](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medications). I will then ban the tag because it has come back multiple times

Comment: I just did a pass through the books tag. How do you want us to note this?

Comment: @Oddthinking edit this question, maybe adding a `<del>`

Comment: I've started a [chat room for this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31304/meta-tag-cleanup-discussion) so we can keep discussion out of comments here

Comment: Should tag-fixers limit themselves to bumping at most 5 stale posts per day?

Comment: @Oddthinking  You seem to have marked news as ready to be deleted but never deleted it.  Someone just tried to edit it.  Maybe it would be better to delete it?

Comment: @Brythan: Hmmm... Someone higher up than me has banned "news" as a new tag. I am working on deleting the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

[hollywood](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood)

This is being used as a synonym for [movies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) I believe.

Update: [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete)

Comment: Are there any questions about the physical place? If not, just burninate: merge and create a synonym to movies (once fixed) :-)

Comment: None were about the physical place, all have been removed. Synonym to [tag:movies] coming up presently.